# Confusion on notation in the definition of reflexivity.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, notation

This is a very silly question i assume to most of you but how would I read this

$\forall x \in X : (x,x) \in R$

I don't quite know what the colon indicates and this definition is used to define reflexivity .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means about as much as the period at the end of this sentence. It is inserted to avoid confusion. Without it, readers may wonder what is meant by $X(x,x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a hold over of the dot notation used in [Principia Mathematica](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/), which has mainly been replaced by bracketing.   It is basically just a punctuation mark to visually separate the quantifier's restriction from its scope. $$\forall x\in S:P(x)\\\forall x\in S~\big(P(x)\big)\\\forall x\in S~P(x)$$

Comment: keep Good ol newton

Answer (score -1):

Normally the colon is read as "such that"

∀ ∈  :(,) ∈

For all $x$ in {the set} X such that $(x,x)$ {$x$ maps to itself} in {the binary relation} R {which is a subset of X}.

Comment: If the quantifier were $\exists$, I would not read the colon as "such that", but this sounds unnatural with $\forall$. Instead, I would simply read this as "for all $x$ in $X$, $(x,x)$ is in $R$."